# How to print the current value of a slider?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am starting to learn sliders and other basic components in react native. I would like to print the current value of the slider in the terminal. I tried putting `console.log()` in different places, but didn't know what I was doing and got errors.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Slider, View, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sliderValue: "0",
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          padding: 20,
          justifyContent: "center",
          backgroundColor: "#ecf0f1",
        }}>
        <Text style = {{ color: "black" }}>
          Value of this slider is : {this.state.sliderValue}
        </Text>
        <Slider
          maximumValue = {10}
          minimumValue = {0}
          step = {1}
          value = {this.state.sliderValue}
          onValueChange = {sliderValue => this.setState({ sliderValue })}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use a separate function for `onValueChange` callback and then in that function use console log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have many options here, I'll give you 2.
You can just console log in your render method

```
render() {
  console.log(this.state.sliderValue);
  //the reset of your code
}
```

Or you can do it inline with the setState call

```
onValueChange = {sliderValue => console.log(sliderValue) || this.setState({ sliderValue })}
```